# How to fix custom indents in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to make my CV look more professional, and am stuck with the following indent:

[image]

No matter what I do, the 2018-2012 part won't go left.

Layout>indent doesn't do anything for me.

---

View>ruler allows me to change the start column from which text starts, but I can't seem to reset it for all the paragraph and have something standard.

How can I make the indent the same and
How can I make the indent custom (and not default), for the paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

Indentation depends on many factors and so I can't say whether this solution will work for you or not, but this should fix your problem with indentation.

**To make the indentation same**:

- Place your cursor at the end of 2008-2012 and press <kbd>Home</kbd> button. This will bring the cursor at the very beginning of that line. (You can also place the cursor at the very beginning of the line manually)
- Now go to 'Home' tab and click the small arrow in the 'Paragraph' section:

[image]

- Change the 'Left' indentation to some negative value:

[image]

*(This will make that particular line move left towards the margin).* You can adjust that negative value to match the indentation of previous lines. Your indentation issue for that line will be fixed.

**To apply this custom indentation to all paragraphs**:

Select everything using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and repeat the same process.

I hope this helps. Tell me how it does :)